# What's the starting loadout (especially ammo) on the Challenge map?

Tags: sniper-ghost-warrior

The single-player Challenge map (from the Second Strike DLC) increases the difficulty compared to the vanilla game by showing only the minimum amount of information on the HUD. Among the things that aren't shown are hit points (not a big deal since getting shot is a very bad idea anyway), number of health syringes, and most importantly, ammo count. While I can keep track of how many rounds I have left before having to reload, I don't even know how many I start out with, and thus, whether I should conserve ammo or feel free to eliminate all hostiles I encounter.

Does anyone know what the starting loadout on the Challenge map is, especially in terms of ammo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply firing the weapons until they ran out of ammo, I've determined the following loadout:

- sniper rifle - 60 rounds (10 per clip)
- silenced pistol - 60 rounds (12 per clip)
- throwing knives - 2

That should be enough to take out all enemies on the map, unless you have really bad aim. You can also find some ammo halfway through the big camp you have to sneak into (the one where you first took out the three guards in towers), in the second building you go through.

You also get 3 health syringes, but no grenades/claymores/C4.